# Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction - React Native, Realm

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

```
onPressFavourites(item) {
    let realm = Realm.open({
    path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath +'/trees.realm',
    schema: [sightingSchema, treeSchema],
    schemaVersion: 7,
   }).then(realm => {
    if(item.favourites === 0) {
     realm.write(() => {
        item.favourites = 1;
        item.favouritesColour = '#91b54d';
    });

    } else {
        realm.write(() => {
      item.favourites = 0;
        item.favouritesColour = 'transparent';
          }); 
    }
        }); 
    alert(item.favourites)// Update a property value
    }
```

I am trying to update an object in the Realm when a button is clicked however I get the error

"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction."

This code was working a couple days ago but is now throwing the above error.

I am still learning React Native and Realm but from my understanding and following examples and the Realm docs, I am using the correct code so it should work.

**EDIT**

Seems the realm and write transactions were fine.
We were able to find a roundabout way to fix it however now the updates don't display until the app is refreshed.

It seems the error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.` was produced when using the argument `item` to define the chosen Realm Object. However, if we create a variable related to the `item`, it doesn't produce that error. Any ideas why this would happen?

```
onPressFavourites(item) {
    //console.log(realm);
    let realm = Realm.open({
        path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath +'/trees.realm',
        schema: [sightingSchema, treeSchema],
        schemaVersion: 7,
    }).then(realm => {
        let trees = realm.objects('TreeInfo');
        for(var i=0; i<trees.length;i++){
            if(trees[i].commonName == item.commonName){
                var chosen = trees[i];
                break;
            }  
        }
        console.log(chosen);
        if(item.favourites === 0) {
                realm.write(() => {
                    //item.favourites = 1;
                    //item.favouritesColour = '#91b54d';
                    chosen.favourites = 1;
                    chosen.favouritesColour = '#91b54d';
                });
        }
        else {
            realm.write(() => {
                chosen.favourites = 0;
                chosen.favouritesColour = 'transparent';
            }); 
        }
    });
    alert(item.favourites)// Update a property value
}
```

**EDIT**

```
render() { 
    var treeList = this.state.trees;
    console.log(treeList);
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
     //var  tree = treeList[0];
    return(
        <Container>
            <Header searchBar style={styles.searchBar}>
              <Item style={styles.searchBarInner}>
                <Icon name="ios-search" />
                <Input placeholder="Search" />
              </Item>
            </Header>
            <List dataArray={treeList}
                renderRow={(item) => 
                    <ListItem style={styles.ListItem} button={true}>
                        <ListButton item={item}
                            onSelect={(item) => this.saveTreeInfo(item)}
                            onSelectFavourites={(item) =>                               this.onPressFavourites(item)
                            }
                        /> 
                    </ListItem>
                }
            >
            </List>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Above is where `item` is being passed to the `onPressFavourites` function. `item` is being generated from an array of Realm Objects `treelist` and displayed in a list.

The `treelist` array comes from the variable `this.state.trees` which is displayed below.

```
filterContent(){
        Realm.open({
            path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath +'/trees.realm',
            schema: [sightingSchema, treeSchema],
            schemaVersion: 7,
            }).then(realm => {
                let trees = realm.objects('TreeInfo');
                let length = trees.length;
                let treeRealm = trees.sorted('commonName');

                console.log(this.state.leafEdges);
                if (this.state.leafEdges === 'smooth') {
                    var smoothLeaf = treeRealm.filtered('leafEdges CONTAINS "Smooth"');
                    this.setState({trees:smoothLeaf});
                }
                if (this.state.leafEdges === 'toothed') {
                    var toothedLeaf = treeRealm.filtered('leafEdges CONTAINS "Toothed"');
                    this.setState({trees:toothedLeaf});
                }
                if (this.state.leafEdges === 'notsure') {
                    this.setState({trees:treeRealm});
                }
                else if (this.state.leafEdges === 'null') {
                    this.setState({trees:treeRealm});   
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Except that `Realm.open()` doesn't return a Realm (see https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#.open), I can't see any obvious wrong-doings.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I could do to fix it?

Comment: The two `write`s are looking fine but is `item` and `sightingSchema` or `treeSchema`?

Comment: The `item` is in the `treeSchema` but I believe you have to open both schemas if they are nested objects? The `sightingSchema` is an object in the `treeSchema`.

Comment: If you have more schemas in your Realm elsewhere, opening with those two might trigger a migration. Maybe it is easier to pass `realm` as an argument to `onPressFavourites`.

Comment: Does the Realm instance where `item` is from, has the exact same configuration?

Comment: I only have one Realm instance throughout the app but I have posted an update with way `item` is generated. If its easier, my email is Taylor.pringle@aut.ac.nz and I can send you the whole code.

Answer (score 4):

Answer in English:

The `trees` has something about `realm`, so you cannot change it. Just copy a new Array like this:

`let trees = realm.objects('TreeInfo');`

```
var arr=[];
for (let i = 0;trees && i < trees .length; i++) {
  var item=trees[i];
  var item2={
    id: item.id,
     ....
  }
arr.push(item2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should improve the syntax

```
let order = {...bla, bla,bla}
realm.write(() => {
            realm.create("order", order);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

这个trees 里面关联了realm里的一些东西，所以不能改变，要重新复制一个数组，像这样

let trees = realm.objects('TreeInfo');

```
var arr=[];
for (let i = 0;trees && i < trees .length; i++) {
  var item=trees[i];
  var item2={
    id: item.id,
     ....
  }
arr.push(item2);
}
```

Comment: what about the same answer in english? :)